# Alter a route according the current user

Tags: entities, routes

I'm on D 9.4.x, trying to redirect the `node.add` route to a custom one, only when the current user has the right role\permission.

So I don't think I can't work in the alterRoutes but I probably need to override the controller of that route.
In a custom RouteSubscriber I have:

```php
protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('node.add')) {
      $route->setDefault('_controller', '\Drupal\my_module\myController::alterRoute');
    }
  }
```

and in the controller

```php
  public function alterRoute(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    if ($my_condition) {
       return $this->redirect('my_route');
    }
    else {
      $node_type = $route_match->getRawParameter('node_type');
      return $this->redirect('node.add', ['node_type' => $node_type]); //this goes loop
    }
  }
```

This code causes a loop, as when the condition fails the redirect return in my custom controller and so on.
Any idea I could implement this feature? Thanks

Comment: and you can't do if `($route = $collection->get('node.add') && $my_condition)` in your RouteSubscriber?

Comment: No, because that condition depend on the current user, and the alterRoute is run only "After building routes (e.g. when a module is enabled or when caches are cleared)," and not when the page is loaded.

Comment: Potentially in your else section you'd need to just re-create what core is doing for this route (aka provide the node edit form). Something like this might work https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256841/alter-existing-route-to-a-different-route-for-a-specific-content-type-node-using

Comment: Yes, or extend the core controller so that you don't need to re-create what core is doing. But in this case the route points at a generic entity form, which I would leave alone to avoid conflicts with other modules. You can redirect in other places, like an event subscriber, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2013014, or in a form alter hook targeting this specific entity form, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/311211/clarify-difference-between-hook-form-type-alter-and-hook-form-type-edit-alter

Comment: Thanks to both, I started to extends the `HtmlEntityFormController` to "re-create" the core logics, but then the suggestions of @4uk4 let to me easily implement what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @4uk4 I've develop an Event Subscriber where is easy to implement the logic I need:

```php
  public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event) {
     if ($this->account->hasPermission('my permission')) {
      return;
    }

    $route_name = $this->routeMatch->getRouteName();
    
    if($route_name === 'node.add') {
     $url = Url::fromRoute('custom_route')->toString();
     $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
     $event->setResponse($response);
    }

  }
```